# The Stone-Cech compactification of a countable disjoint union of closed intervals

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be the disjoint union of a countably infinite number of copies of $[0,1]$. Is $\beta X$ strictly bigger than $\beta{\bf N}\times [0,1]$?

I am thinking of a bounded sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ converging pointwise to the characteristic function of $(\frac12, 1]$. Then this bounded sequence defines a bounded continuous function $f$ on $X$ and I am doubtful that $f$ can be extended continuously to $\beta{\bf N}\times [0,1]$. But I haven't been able to finish the argument or visualise the "missing" ultrafilters, if any.

**Note:** Glicksberg's Theorem states that for Tychonov spaces $X$ and $Y$, $\beta (X\times Y)$ is $\beta X \times\beta Y$ precisely when $X\times Y$ is the pseudocompact product of two infinite spaces (where $Z$ pseudocompact means that every continuous real-valued mapping on $Z$ is bounded). This is in Russell C. Walker, *The Stone-Cech Compactification*, chapter 8. The space $[0,1]\times {\bf N}$ is not pseudocompact, so there are definitely other $z$-ultrafilters. But what do they look like, i.e. how should one think about $\beta ([0,1]\times {\bf N})$?

Comment: Ultra filters don't depend on the topology.  However the topology may lead to two ultra filters converging to the same point.

Comment: It's not so much ultrafilters as $z$-ultrafilters that we should be thinking about (if I am remembering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cardinality of $\beta(\mathbf{N}\times[0,1])$ is just $2^\mathfrak{c}$: it has a base $\mathcal{B}$ of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ and because it is Hausdorff the map $x\mapsto\{B\in\mathcal{B}:x\in B\}$ is injective, hence the cardinality is at most $2^\mathfrak{c}$.
On the other hand the space contains a copy of $\beta\mathbf{N}$ so its cardinality is at least $2^\mathfrak{c}$.
So $\beta\mathbf{N}$, $\beta\mathbf{N}\times[0,1]$, and $\beta(\mathbf{N}\times[0,1])$ all have the same cardinality.

On the other hand: the natural map from $\beta(\mathbf{N}\times[0,1])$ to $\beta\mathbf{N}\times[0,1]$ is surjective and definitely not injective: if $u$ is a free ultrafilter and $t\in[0,1]$ then the preimage of the point $(u,t)$ has cardinality $2^\mathfrak{c}$.

See [The Cech-Stone compactification of the real line](https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/%7Ehart/37/publications/the_papers/betaR.pdf)

Comment: Many thanks. Thinking of ${\bf N}\times [0,1]$ as a closed subset of ${\bf R}$ is helpful.